# Opening a binary (32 bit signed integer .dat) file into numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 32 bit signed integer .dat file with two arrays where the data is interleaved. I want to open the data into two separate numpy arrays.

I have tried to open it using numpy 'fromfile'.

```
import numpy as np

newarray = np.fromfile('file.dat',dtype=int)
print newarray
```

From my file, this prints

```
[ 83886080 16777216 251658240 ..., 0 50331648 16777216]
```

Which is odd because I know the two arrays should start like

```
[  1   0   0  ...]
[  15  5   11 ...]
```

Based on my understanding of the interleaved data I was expecting the above code to give me 1 array which looked something like

```
[  1   15   0   5 ...]
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? I can post the file if it would help.

Comment: @martineau Sorry I should have mentioned that I tried this and got an array `[ 83886080  16777216 251658240 ...,         0  50331648  16777216]`, so that didn't appear to work. Note also that I'd prefer this as two arrays also.

Comment: @martineau Oh wow I misread the information. I'll edit it now. It is indeed a 32 bit signed integer file (it was being loaded into a floating point array in a different program). How would I go about reading it into the array myself?

Comment: Try `dtype=np.int32`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data = np.fromfile('file.dat', dtype=np.int32)
arr1 = data[::2]
arr2 = data[1::2]
```

or

```
data = np.memmap('file.dat', dtype=np.int32, mode='r')
arr1 = data[::2]
arr2 = data[1::2]
```